# Problems while trying to generate pandas dataframe columns from regulars expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, nlp

I am working with a number of `.txt` files allocated in a directory. From all of these files, how should I extract specific words or chunks of text (i.e. sentences, paragraphs, and tokens defined by a regex) and place them into a pandas dataframe (i.e. tabular format), preserving a column with the name of each file? So far, I created this function that does this task (I know... it ain't perfect):

In:

```
import glob, os, re
import pandas as pd
regex = r'\<the regex>\b'
ind = 'path/dir'
out = 'path/dir'
f ='path/redirected/output/'


def foo(ind, reg, out):
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(in_directory, '*.txt')):
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            stuff = re.findall(a_regex, file.read(), re.M)
            #my_list = [str([j.split()[0] for j in i]) for i in stuff]

            lis = [t[::2] for t in stuff]
            cont = ' '.join(map(str, lis))
            print(cont)
            with open(out, 'a') as f:
                print(filename.split('/')[-1] + '\t' + cont, file = f)


foo(directory, regex, out)
```

Then the output is redirected to third file:

Out:

```
fileName1.txt       
fileName2.txt       stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk
fileName3.txt       stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk
....
fileNameN.txt       stringOrChunk
```

Then this is how I create the dataframe from the previous file (yeah I know its awful):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(/path/of/f/, sep='\t', names = ['file_names','col1'])
df.to_csv('/pathOfNewCSV.csv', index=False, sep='\t')
```

And Finally:

```
    file_names  col1
0   fileName1.txt   NaN
1   fileName2.txt   stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk...
2   fileName3.txt   stringOrChunk stringOrChunk stringOrChunk...
3   fileName4.txt   stringOrChunk
.....
N   fileNameN.txt   stringOrChunk
```

So, any idea of how to do this in a more pythonic and efficient way?

**Update**

I uploaded a .zip with some docs as [data](https://ufile.io/22e6), so if we want to extract all the adverbs from the documents we should do:

```
a_regex = r"\w+ly"
directory = '/Users/user/Desktop/Docs/'
output_dir = '/Users/user/Desktop/'

foo(ind, reg, out)
```

Then, it should create a table with all the adverbs of the documents:

```
Files            words
doc1.txt    
doc2.txt    
doc3.txt     DIRECTLY PROBABLY EARLY 
doc4.txt
```

Any idea of how to enhance the above function? Additionally, I don't know if this is the best way to do this [information extraction task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction) (i.e. just using regex). What about using an string indexer like [woosh](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-quick-introduction) project or what about nltk?

**UPDATE**

For example, consider creating a [dataframe](http://pastebin.com/RTQ7BAKT) that extracts all the sentences that contain the word: `JESUITS`:

```
    Files   words1  words2  words3  words4
0   doc1.txt    A GOVERNMENT SPOKESMAN HAS ANNOUNCED THAT WITH...   NaN     NaN     NaN
1   doc2.txt    11/12/98 "THERE WAS NO TORTURE OR MISTREATMENT...   NaN     NaN     NaN
2   doc3.txt    WHAT WE HAD PREDICTED HAS OCCURRED. CRISTIANI ...   SO, THE QUESTION IS: WHO GAVE THE ORDER TO KIL...   THE MASSACRE OF THE JESUITS WAS NOT A PERSONAL...   LET US REMEMBER THAT AFTER THE MASSSACRE OF TH...
3   doc4.txt    IN 11/12/98 OUR VIEW, THE ASSASSINS OF THE JES...   THE ASSASSINATION OF THE JESUITS AGAIN CONFIRM...   NaN     NaN
```

Comment: You may want to read [this](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html)

Comment: Actually I all ready read it @MaxU, that's why I mentioned NLTK.

Answer (score 2):

I am not totally sure I understand this question but the herein snippet is some best effort to approach this with `nltk`.

```
from glob import glob
from os.path import join, split

import nltk
import pandas as pd

dir_name = '/tmp/stackovflw/Docs'
file_to_adverb_dict = {}
nltk_adverb_tags = {'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS'}  # taken from nltk.help.upenn_tagset()

for full_file_path in glob(join(dir_name, '*.txt')):
    with open(full_file_path, 'rb') as f:
        _, file_name = split(full_file_path)
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(f.read().lower()) # lower -> seems that nltk behaves differently when the text is uppercase - try it...
        adverbs_in_file = [token for token, tag in nltk.pos_tag(tokens) if tag in nltk_adverb_tags]
        # consider using a "set" here to remove duplicates
        file_to_adverb_dict[file_name] = ' '.join(adverbs_in_file).upper()  #converting it back to uppercase (your input is all uppercase)

print pd.DataFrame(file_to_adverb_dict.items(), columns=['file_names', 'col1'])
#   file_names                                               col1
# 0   doc4.txt  PROBABLY ABROAD ALFONSO HOWEVER ALWAYS ALREADY...
# 1   doc1.txt                                                NOT
# 2   doc3.txt  DIRECTLY NOT SO SOLELY NOT PROBABLY NOT EVEN N...
# 3   doc2.txt
```

One more note, if you simply want to find words that end with "ly" in a specific folder, `grep` is your friend:

```
$ grep  -o -i -E  '\w+ly' *.txt
doc3.txt:DIRECTLY
doc3.txt:SOLELY
doc3.txt:PROBABLY
doc3.txt:EARLY
doc4.txt:PROBABLY
```

`-o` gives you the match only and not the whole line
`-i` ignores case
`-E` extended regex

Use awk to reduce by file name:

```
 $ grep  -o -i -E  '\w+ly' *.txt | awk -F':' '{a[$1]=a[$1] " "  $2}END{for( i in a ) print  i,"," a[i]}'
doc4.txt , PROBABLY
doc3.txt , DIRECTLY SOLELY PROBABLY EARLY
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!, I got the following exception: `TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object`, probably this is since I am in python3?. This is the full trace: 
`---> 15         tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(f.read().lower()) # lower -> seems that nltk behaves differently when the text is uppercase - try it...
     16         adverbs_in_file = [token for token, tag in nltk.pos_tag(tokens) if tag in nltk_adverb_tags]
     17         # consider using a "set" here to remove duplicates`

Comment: Also, I was expecting to catch, chunks of sentences, for that reason I decided to do not use NLTK, for instance I would like to extract all the sentences that have the word: `JESUITS`. I updated the question with an example.

Comment: To fix the `TypeError` replace `open(full_file_path, 'rb')` with `open(full_file_path, 'r')` (my bad).

Comment: For sentences with `JESUITS`: you can just split the content of each file by `.` (or `,` or whatever), then look for the word `JESUITS` while you are iterating over the sentences.